# How to include Partial Views in a page?

Tags: nativescript

I've been trying to test partial views with nativescript but I cannot seem to get the page to load the partial view content.

Here is my main container view:

```
<Page id="tabsPage" class="page" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:t1="views/tab-test/partial-views/tab1">
    <ScrollView>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="test button"/>
<Button tap="GoToTab2" text="Go To Tab 2"/> 
    <!-- <SegmentedBar selectedIndex="0" selectedIndexChanged="segBarSelected">
        <SegmentedBar.items>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Tab 1" />
        </SegmentedBar.items>
    </SegmentedBar> -->

        <t1:tab1 id="tab1" />
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

tab1.xml

```
<Button class="btn btn-primary" text="test button"/>
<Button tap="GoToTab2" text="Go To Tab 2"/>
```

As you can see I ruled out that the button content in tab1.xml displays independently on the main page but as soon as I do the include statement `<t1:tab1 id="tab1" />`, nothing displays.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The ScrollView can contain a **single** root element. The same practice should be considered when creating your custom components (nice blog post [here](http://blog.bradleygore.com/2016/03/12/custom-nativescript-components/)). Try wrapping the buttons in your custom component in StackLayout (or another layout) and do the same for the content of your ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

```js
tab1.js
----------

function onLoad(args) {

    var container = args.object;
    container.bindingContext = container;
}
```

```html
<Page id="tabsPage" class="page" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:t1="views/tab-test/partial-views">


tab1.xml
----------
<GridLayout columns="80,*,80" rows="100" style="background:#fff;opacity:0.95;padding:10 10;margin-bottom:20" loaded="onLoad">
  
<Button class="btn btn-primary" text="test button"/>
<Button tap="GoToTab2" text="Go To Tab 2"/>
</GridLayout>
```